# Evaluation Of Formula (Five Variables)

Tags: inequality

$a\geq 1$, $b\geq 1$, $c\geq 1$, $x\geq 1$, $y\geq 1$

Evaluate the range of $~$ $\dfrac{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(x+1)(y+1)}{a+b+c+x+y+1}$

I have no solution but hope that there exist one using no calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strategy:

1. For fixed $b,c,x,y$, this attains its minimum at $a=1$.
2. By symmetry the expression is minimal at $a=b=c=x=y=1$, when it is equal to $\frac{32}{6}$.
3. The expression is unbounded, and continuous (sorry, a little bit of calculus), so every value above $\frac{32}{6}$ can be attained.

Note that this is just a sketch, there are many details missing.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to any of your parameters $a, b, c, x$ and $y,$ the derivatives of your functions are all positive.
Then the minimum value of the function is obtained for $a=b=c=x=y=1,$ that is to say $16/3.$